# LSTM or other RNN package for R

Tags: r, neural-network, rnn

I saw some impressive result from LSTM models producing Shakespeare like texts. I was wondering if an LSTM package exists for R. I googled for it but only found packages for Python and Julia. (maybe there are some performance issue which explains why these programs are more preferred over R) Do You know about an LSTM (or at least an RNN) package for R? If exists are there any tutorials for using them?

Comment: Example link of such results: http://karpathy.github.io/2015/05/21/rnn-effectiveness/ (not sure if this is one you have seen)

Comment: @NeilSlater Yes, that's one nice implementation I saw but unfortunately not for R.

Comment: I updated my answer to mention the now available LSTM and GRU algorithms in [rnn](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rnn).

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the rnn package (full disclosure, I am the author). It implements a multilayer RNN, GRU, and LSTM directly in R, i.e. not an underlying C++ library, so you should also be able to read the code and understand what is going on.

```
install.packages('rnn')
```

The CRAN version is quite up to date, but the [GitHub version](https://github.com/bquast/rnn) is bleeding edge and can be installed using:

```
if (!require('devtools')) install.packages('devtools')
devtools::install_github('bquast/rnn')
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice package! I just started experimenting with it. I wonder if you have made any speed comparison with other implementations.

Comment: if its in R is it really slow?

Comment: not really, it's fast enough for reasonable work, there are ofc memory limitations

Answer (score 7):

[Keras](https://keras.rstudio.com/) is also now available for R. Here's an [example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kerasR/vignettes/introduction.html#recurrent-neural-networks-rnn-with-imdb) of an LSTM with the R API.

Answer (score 4):

You might have to extend another package to implement LSTM and RNN in R. Here are some packages to get you started:

- [deepnet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deepnet/) Implements a variety of deep learning architectures
- [darch](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/darch/index.htmlh) A deep architecture
- [H2O](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/index.html) An open-source company with deep learning packages

Answer (score 4):

I found this page, but the R package seems not to be open source :
[link.](http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~idfah/main/projects/rnn)

Comment: It seems promising. According to the author he will publish it on CRAN when finished.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [mxnet](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet). It is a distributed library for deep learning. It supports C++, python, scala and R. There are many examples with R. [Here](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/blob/master/R-package/vignettes/CharRnnModel.Rmd) you have an example of LSTM in R with this library.